# Send information through Socket.IO, using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, socket.io, imap

*Ok i'm gonna start off by stating that i don't really understand everything i'm doing and i'm not trying to use this website for people to solve my problems for free. I'm a self-learning developer wanna-be and sometimes i need a little guidance. Hopefully you guys can help me with this*

---

## **WHAT I DID:**

I am successfully running [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) on my server and am able to transmit information in real time from client(browser) to client(browser), using JS. Combining it with ajax scripts i successfully create, insert, update databases, run php scripts, etc. This means an action done by one user can easily be transmitted and interpreted by other user. Which is exactly what socket.io was made for

---

## **WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**

PHP script to go through the server's `imap` and check for emails with the `'RECENT'` tag and when such is present - send notification to the respectful users with Socket.IO

---

## **WHAT WAS UNSUCCESSFUL:**

***Running the PHP as a background server process***. The JS script that was supposed to `'emit'` the information was just output in the console and not executed.

---

## **WHAT I NEED FROM YOU GUYS:**

Advice. ***What is the best approach to achieve that?***

---

**WHAT I AM CONSIDERING**

[Elephant.IO](http://elephant.io/) seems like my solution, but i am not sure exactly how it works and if it is the correct answer.

P.S.: I am sorry i didn't post any code (Which i will do if you want me to), i just thought it is not necessary since my problem is logical and concerns general knowledge, which i missed in my 5 years not being in school studying this...

## **THANK YOU!**

Comment: The question is: _Why?_ Why do you want to let PHP do the work and notify your running node-server when you could just let js itself check for mails? But to answer one of your questions: You can't just output JS from PHP, this will not work. You need to connect to your node-server from PHP somehow (TCP) or send an UDP-Package.

Comment: How do you check imap with js?

Comment: I mean, sure, i can do an ajax request easily and check, but he 'RECENT' tag disappears after a second, which means i have to make requests every second ? I don't think this is the way.

Comment: The same way you do it with php. You use some sort of imap-library or write it yourself. For example: https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap